# SQL: Row number is different when sorting on columns with null values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my C# application I'm using the following query to search for a particular string:

```
;WITH selectRows AS (SELECT *, row = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY <column_name>) FROM <table_name>)
SELECT row FROM selectRows WHERE <column_name> LIKE '%<search_string>%' COLLATE <collate> ORDER BY row;
```

This particular query always worked fine for me, even when the colum_name for the OVER ORDER BY clause was a column that contained null values. Yesterday I tried to search on a somewhat bigger SQL table (+- 1 million records), it suprised me that I got different row_numbers returned without changing the query between the executions. This only seem to happen on bigger tables and when the column_name for the OVER ORDER BY clause contains any null values. When the column_name is pointed to a column WITHOUT null values the query returns the same result over and over again.

I also tried the following query, but this did not work as well:

```
;WITH selectRows AS (SELECT *, row = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ISNULL(<column_name>, '')) FROM <table_name>)
SELECT row FROM selectRows WHERE <column_name> LIKE '%<search_string>%' COLLATE <collate> ORDER BY row;
```

Note: both queries were tested on SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server 2008. The searched table also had a Primary Key (clustered) index on a Identity column and a nonclustered index on the column_name that is used for the OVER ORDER BY clause.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified an ordering criterion that is not a total order. Example: You order on a column that is always zero. That way the CTE can output a different row order each time.

You are filtering *after* ordering. That means your filter runs on different rows each time. It might happen to have a lot of matching rows or not.

In general SQL queries are not 100% deterministic thanks to certain constructs. There are more than this one.

Fix: Specify a total order. Use *anything* to break ties such as `ORDER BY X, ID`. As a habit I *always* specify a total order.

Comment: I tried the same thing just before you posted this and guess what it is working! Thanks!